# Why 'LoadableComponent' skipping on load() method?

Tags: design-patterns, selenium

I"m trying to use for the first time selenium 'LoadableComponent' to load my page.

Here by my simple code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NavigateTo {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void NavigateToMain() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Login login = new Login(driver).get();
    }
}
```

===================

```
import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.LoadableComponent;

public class Login extends LoadableComponent<Login> {

    private WebDriver driver;

    private By title = By.cssSelector(".anim-btn.green span");

    public Login(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {
        System.out.println("Navigating to Bizzabo home page");
        driver.get("int-www.bizzabo.com");

    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        assertEquals("Get started", driver.findElement(title).getText());
    }
}
```

Why when calling to: 'Login login = new Login(driver).get()' it not going first through the load() method, but straight through the 'isLoaded()' method?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

That is just **by design**. Is is meant to execute the **loading** only **once** thus increasing testing performance.

If you need a **forced reload** you could simply declare the overridden `load()` function as `public` (the overriding `load()` function in the sub class to be exact). Then just in case you can call `load()` instead of `get()`:

```
public class Login extends LoadableComponent<Login> {
    ...

    /**
     * Load the web page.
     */
    @Override
    public final void load() {
        driver.get(...);
    }

    ...
}
```

If you don't feel comfortable with breaking the design a little by extending the `protected` modifier to `public`, you could extend the `LoadableComponent` class and add a `public` `reload()` function:

```
public class LoadablePO extends LoadableComponent<LoadablePO> {
    ...

    /**
     * Force a reload (by circumventing the call of isLoaded()).
     */
    public final void reload() {
        this.load();
    }

    /**
     * Load the web page.
     */
    @Override
    protected final void load() {
        driver.get(...);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the isLoaded function first, when it failed it will automatically call the load function